# create new tab in puppeteer inside a loop cause Navigation timeout

Tags: puppeteer

Recently I am learning puppeteer using their docs and try to **scrape** some information.

### First approach

**First** I collect a list of url from the mainpage. **Second** I create a new tab and go those url iterately and collect some data. I doubt when I enter the loop the new tab didn't work as I expect and freezed without giving any data. Eventually I got a error `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`. Is there any better approach?

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const mainpage = await browser.newPage();

  console.log('goto main page'.green);
  await mainpage.goto(mainURL);

  console.log('collecting some url'.green);
  const URLS = await mainpage.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('.result-actions a'),
      (element) => element.href
    )
  );
  if (typeof URLS[0] === 'string') console.log('OK'.green);

  console.log('collecting finished'.green);

  const newTab= await browser.newPage();

  console.log('create new tab'.green);

  var data = [];

  for (let i = 0, n = URLS.length; i < n; i++) {
    //console.log(URLS[i]);

    // use this new tab to collect some data then close this tab
    // continue this process

    await newTab.waitForNavigation();
    await newTab.goto(URLS[i]);
    await newTab.waitForSelector('.profile-phone-column span a');
    console.log('Go each url using new tab'.green);

    // collecting data
    
    data.push(collected_data);
    // close this tab
    await collectNamePage.close();
    console.log(data);
  }
  await mainpage.close();
  await browser.close();
  console.log('closing browser'.green);
})();
```

### Second approach

This time I want to skip the part where I collect those data using a new tab. Hence I collect my urls using `page.$$()` and try to iterating using `for...of` over `urls` and collect my data using `elementHandle.$(selector)` but this approach also failed.

I am getting frustrated. Am I doing it wrong way or I didn't understand their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your script, you do not need `newTab.waitForNavigation();` at all. Usually, this is used when the navigation is caused by some event. When you just use `.goto()`, the page loading is waited automatically.
2. Even if you need `waitForNavigation()`, you usually do not `await` it before the navigation triggered, otherwise you just get the timeout. You `await` it with navigation trigger together:

   ```js
   await Promise.all([element.click(),  page.waitForNavigation()]);
   ```

So try to just delete `await newTab.waitForNavigation();`.

Also, do not close the new tab in the loop, delete it after the loop.

---

Edited script:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const mainURL = 'https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/illinois/';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const mainpage = await browser.newPage();

  console.log('goto main page');
  await mainpage.goto(mainURL);

  console.log('collecting urls');
  const URLS = await mainpage.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('.result-actions a'),
      (element) => element.href
    )
  );
  if (typeof URLS[0] === 'string') console.log('OK');
  console.log('collection finished');

  const collectNamePage = await browser.newPage();

  console.log('create new tab');

  var data = [];

  for (let i = 0, totalUrls = URLS.length; i < totalUrls; i++) {
    console.log(URLS[i]);

    await collectNamePage.goto(URLS[i]);
    await collectNamePage.waitForSelector('.profile-phone-column span a');
    console.log('create new tab and go there');

    // collecting data
    const [name, phone] = await collectNamePage.evaluate(
      () => [
        document.querySelector('.profile-middle .name-title-column h1').innerText,
        document.querySelector('.profile-phone-column span a').innerText
      ]
    );
    data.push({ name, phone });
  }

  console.log(data);
  await collectNamePage.close();

  await mainpage.close();
  await browser.close();
  console.log('closing browser');
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your response @vsemozhebuty. Now I get new Error `Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.` [here](https://pastebin.com/SWQGEHZ6) is the full console log. I guess this problem occur when you are trying to run a function, but the target (tab) was already closed. Any suggestion? And why `await newTab.$('selector_thing').innerText;` is seem undefined? Isn't it should be the desire text as I can clearly know that node exit

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to tell until you provide the real code (currently your example has omissions and editing artifacts — for example, what is `collectNamePage`?).

Comment: As for `await newTab.$('selector_thing').innerText;` - you should not confuse traditional DOM elements and their API (`.innerText`) with element handlers that are returned by many puppeteer functions. See for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388455/get-href-attribute-in-pupeteer-node-js/55391319#55391319

Comment: Then [here](https://pastebin.com/saemnJUu) is the full code @vsemozhebuty. It will be great help if you help me to resolve that issue

Comment: Yes finally get those data. Thanks to clear me between ElementHandles vs traditional DOM element. But still have the `Execution context was destroyed` Error

Comment: I've edited your script a bit: just delete `colors` package code and change the data collection way (see in the answer). But I cannot reproduce the errors, sorry, For me, everything works fine.

Comment: It's Ok @vsemozhebuty I resolve that one also sorry to ask too many things. I accepted your answer. Cheers